# JavaScript Object Literal Evaluation and valueOf

Tags: javascript

How is the following code segment evaluates to 0.25 ?  I don't understand how object literals are working.

```
({valueOf: function() { return 1}} / 4)
```

All others below evaluate to NaN:

```
({prop1: function() { return 1}} / 4)

({valueOf: 1} / 4)

({valueOf: "1"} / 4)
```

Also is there something special have the property named 'valueOf' ?

Comment: `valueOf` must be a function. Certain operators may call `valueOf`, like `/`.

Answer (score 1):

[Type coercion](http://webreflection.blogspot.co.nz/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html).

If you call

```
21 + "21" // "2121"
```

Javascript is implicitly coercing the number to a string by calling `toString()` on it.

Similarly, in your example, javascript is implicitly coercing your object to a number by calling [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf).

Answer (score 1):

When you use a [multiplicative operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5) like `/`, the expressions at its left and right are converted to numbers using [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3).

Since you have objects, ToNumber uses [ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1), which calls the [[[DefaultValue]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.11) internal method.

> When the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of *O* is called with hint
>   Number, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *valueOf* be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of object *O* with argument `"valueOf"`.
> 2. If [IsCallable](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.11)(*valueOf*) is **true** then,
>
>    1. Let *val* be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of *valueOf*, with *O* as the this value and an empty argument list.
>         2.If *val* is a primitive value, return *val*.
> 3. Let *toString* be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of object *O* with argument `"toString"`.
> 4. If [IsCallable](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.11)(*toString*) is true then,
>
>    1. Let *str* be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of *toString*, with *O* as the this value and an empty argument list.
>    2. If *str* is a primitive value, return *str*.
> 5. Throw a **TypeError** exception.

In your first example, `valueOf` is callable and returns `1`.

But in the other ones there is no `valueOf` or it isn't callable. So JS calls `toString` (inherited from `Object.prototype`), which returns `"[object Object]"`. That string can't be converted to a number, so `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

`valueOf` is a special case method which gets called when an implicit type conversion from object to scalar is needed. So it's a special name. It is similar to toString(), which gets called whenever you need an implicit type conversion from object to string. See [valueOf on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of:

```
({valueOf: function() { return 1}} / 4)
```

The divide operator is translating the first argument into a number and javascript calls valueOf to do this.

In the case of:

```
({prop1: function() { return 1}} / 4)
```

Javascript doesn't know how to turn your first argument into a number (and it can't find a valueOf function to tell it), therefore the result is not a number (NaN).

In the cases of:

```
({valueOf: 1} / 4)

({valueOf: "1"} / 4)
```

Although the first argument does have a valueOf member, it is not a function and therefore it isn't used, the result is NaN again